Unable to use Managed Identity to authenticate to SQL Database with pymssql
We are currently executing SQL queries (to create tables and insert sample data) using a username and password during Azure custom deployment.
Here's the flow: We have a Bicep file that calls a shell script, which installs dependencies from requirements.txt. This script then triggers a Python file that connects to SQL Server and executes SQL queries. We’re using pymssql for this, and it's working as expected. However, we need to switch to using managed identity instead of a username and password. Since pymssql doesn’t support managed identity, we’re trying pyodbc. But, when attempting to install pyodbc in the same way through requirements.txt, we encounter the following error:
33.28       error: command 'g++' failed: No such file or directory
33.28       [end of output]
33.28
33.28   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
33.28   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
33.28 Successfully built quart-session
33.28 Failed to build pyodbc
33.29 ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyodbc, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
33.46
33.46 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.0 -> 24.3.1
33.46 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip```


download the correct .whl file for pyodbc from https://pypi.org/project/pyodbc/#files and install it


Error: command 'g++' failed: No such file or directory [end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc

The error is occuring when you are installing pyodbc so the system is not having compiler (g++), which is required to build pyodbc.
I agree with @Pratik Lad's comment,
You can try the below approach:

You can use a Linux-based Azure VM
Run a shell script to setup and for installing dependencies from requirements.txt.

pyodbc requires the unixODBC driver manager & you can install these with:
!apt install unixodbc-dev
!pip install pyodbc

Results:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
unixodbc-dev is already the newest version (2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in /databricks/python3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (4.0.38)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel using %restart_python or dbutils.library.restartPython() to use updated packages.


